# searching a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, search

currently i have a database of music that i have db'd in mysql, now i am writing a php frontend for it, and it will list out everything in a table, it works, but if i search "the beatles" it gives me 453 results(correct) however if i just search "beatles" it results in 0 rows, how would i go about making it able to search for something like that?

heres my current line:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * From `songs` WHERE `Artist` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."'
   OR `Album` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."' OR `Genre` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."'
       OR `Title` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."';";
```

**EDIT** Reformatted query by [@Yacoby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118145/yacoby)

```
 $query2 = "SELECT * "
         . "From `songs` "
         . "WHERE `Artist` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."' "
         .   "OR `Album` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."' "
         .   "OR `Genre` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."' "
         .   "OR `Title` like '".$_REQUEST['q']."';";
```

Comment: please remember to use mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize user input: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 2):

Throw a `%` before and after the search term, in the quotes:

```
WHERE Artist like '%".$_REQUEST['q']."%'
```

That will search for [anything]beatles[anything]

Comment: thanks much, that seemd to help with that situation, i might need to do some more parsing, i forgot to add that above that, i am escaping the info by doing $_REQUEST['q'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['q']);

Comment: Obviously, throw the % around each search string. Or, in your example there, do $_REQUEST['q'] = '%' . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['q']) . '%';

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider parsing your user's input and cleaning it up. Get rid of words like "the" and just use important words in the query like "beatles".

Comment: Also store the record as "Beatles, The", and just do a search `LIKE 'BEATLES%'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect against SQL injections. What if someone enters:

`'; DROP DATABASE music; --`

or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

A `LIKE` query allows you to use SQL wildcards (`%` and `_`). Otherwise it acts exactly as if you were using a regular 'equals' comparison:

```
SELECT .... WHERE somefield LIKE 'beatles';
SELECT .... WHERE somefield='beatles';
```

act exactly the same, whereas

```
SELECT .... WHERE somefield LIKE 'beatles%';
```

finds any record where somefield starts with 'beatles', and

```
SELECT .... WHERE somefield='beatles%';
```

will find only records that contain the literal string 'beatles%' (and note that the % isn't being treated as a wildcard).